# python code works on one file but fails on other

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Hi all so I have this code, which prints out the minimum cost and restaurant id for the item/items. The customer doesnt want to visit multiple restaurants. So for example if he asks for "A,B" then the code should print shop which offers them both , instead of scattering the user requirement around different restaurants (even if some restaurant is offering it cheap).

Also if suppose the user asks for burger.Then if a certain restaurant 'X' is giving a "burger" for 4$, whereas another restaurant 'Y' is giving "burger+tuna+tofu" for $3, then we will tell the user to got for RESTAURANT 'Y', even if it has extra items apart from the 'burger' which user asked for, but we are happy to give them extra items as long as its cheap.

Everythings fine, but the code is strangely behaving differently on two input files(fails on input.csv but runs on input-2.csv) which are of same format, its giving correct output for one whereas fails for another. This is the only minute error I need your help to fix. Please help me , I guess I have hit the wall , cant think beyond it all.

```
def build_shops(shop_text):
    shops = {}
    for item_info in shop_text:
        shop_id,cost,items = item_info.replace('\n', '').split(',')
        cost = float(cost)
        items = items.split('+')

        if shop_id not in shops:
            shops[shop_id] = {}
        shop_dict = shops[shop_id]

        for item in items:
            if item not in shop_dict:
                shop_dict[item] = []
            shop_dict[item].append([cost,items])
    return shops


def solve_one_shop(shop, items):
    if len(items) == 0:
        return [0.0, []]
    all_possible = []
    first_item = items[0]
    if first_item in shop:
        print "SHOP",shop.get(first_item)
    for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
        #print "items,combo=",items,combo
        sub_set = [x for x in items if x not in combo]
        #print "sub_set=",sub_set
        price_sub_set,solution = solve_one_shop(shop, sub_set)
        solution.append([price,combo])
        all_possible.append([price+price_sub_set, solution])

    cheapest = min(all_possible, key=(lambda x: x[0]))
    return cheapest


def solver(input_data, required_items):
    shops = build_shops(input_data)
    #print shops
    result_all_shops = []
    for shop_id,shop_info in shops.iteritems():
        (price, solution) = solve_one_shop(shop_info, required_items)
        result_all_shops.append([shop_id, price, solution])

    shop_id,total_price,solution = min(result_all_shops, key=(lambda x: x[1]))
    print('SHOP_ID=%s' % shop_id)
    sln_str = [','.join(items)+'(%0.2f)'%price for (price,items) in solution]
    sln_str = '+'.join(sln_str)
    print(sln_str + ' = %0.2f' % total_price)



shop_text = open('input-1.csv','rb')    
solver(shop_text,['burger'])
```

**=====input-1.csv=====restaurant_id, price, item**

```
1,2.00,burger
1,1.25,tofulog
1,2.00,tofulog
1,1.00,chef_salad
1,1.00,A+B
1,1.50,A+CCC
1,2.50,A
2,3.00,A
2,1.00,B
2,1.20,CCC
2,1.25,D
```

**=====output & error====:**

```
{'1': {'A': [[1.0, ['A', 'B']], [1.5, ['A', 'CCC']], [2.5, ['A', 'D']]], 'B': [[1.0, ['A', 'B']]], 'D': [[2.5, ['A', 'D']]], 'chef_salad': [[1.0, ['chef_salad']]], 'burger': [[2.0, ['burger']]], 'tofulog': [[1.25, ['tofulog']], [2.0, ['tofulog']]], 'CCC': [[1.5, ['A', 'CCC']]]}, '2': {'A': [[3.0, ['A']]], 'B': [[1.0, ['B']]], 'D': [[1.25, ['D']]], 'CCC': [[1.2, ['CCC']]]}}
SHOP [[2.0, ['burger']]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "work.py", line 55, in <module>
    solver(shop_text,['burger'])
  File "work.py", line 43, in solver
    (price, solution) = solve_one_shop(shop_info, required_items)
  File "work.py", line 26, in solve_one_shop
    for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
KeyError: 'burger'
```

whereas if I run the same code on input-2.csv , and query for solver(shop_text,['A','CCC']), I get correct result

**=====input-2.csv======**

```
1,2.00,A
1,1.25,B
1,2.00,B
1,1.00,A
1,1.00,A+B
1,1.50,A+CCC
1,2.50,A+D
2,3.00,A
2,1.00,B
2,1.20,CCC
2,1.25,D
```

**=========output====**

```
{'1': {'A': [[2.0, ['A']], [1.0, ['A']], [1.0, ['A', 'B']], [1.5, ['A', 'CCC']], [2.5, ['A', 'D']]], 'B': [[1.25, ['B']], [2.0, ['B']], [1.0, ['A', 'B']]], 'D': [[2.5, ['A', 'D']]], 'CCC': [[1.5, ['A', 'CCC']]]}, '2': {'A': [[3.0, ['A']]], 'B': [[1.0, ['B']]], 'D': [[1.25, ['D']]], 'CCC': [[1.2, ['CCC']]]}}
SHOP [[2.0, ['A']], [1.0, ['A']], [1.0, ['A', 'B']], [1.5, ['A', 'CCC']], [2.5, ['A', 'D']]]
SHOP [[1.5, ['A', 'CCC']]]
SHOP [[1.5, ['A', 'CCC']]]
SHOP [[1.5, ['A', 'CCC']]]
SHOP [[1.5, ['A', 'CCC']]]
SHOP [[3.0, ['A']]]
SHOP [[1.2, ['CCC']]]
SHOP_ID=1
A,CCC(1.50) = 1.50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've fixed it...

#### solve_one_shop

The `for` loop should only happen within the `if`, otherwise you get a `KeyError`. Also, I have changed it so that it only returns if `all_possible` contains anything (an empty `list` evaluates to `False`.

**edit** To prevent a `TypeError` I have done assigned to a temporary value `this_subset` and the rest of the loop only happens is it is not `None`.

```
def solve_one_shop(shop, items):
    if len(items) == 0:
        return [0.0, []]
    all_possible = []
    first_item = items[0]
    if first_item in shop:
        for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
            sub_set = [x for x in items if x not in combo]
            this_subset = solve_one_shop(shop, sub_set)
            if this_subset is not None:
                price_sub_set,solution = this_subset
                solution.append([price,combo])
                all_possible.append([price+price_sub_set, solution])

    if all_possible:
        cheapest = min(all_possible, key=(lambda x: x[0]))
        return cheapest
```

#### solver

I have assigned the return value of `solve_one_shop` to an intermediate variable. If this is `None`, then the shop is not added to `result_all_shops`.

**edit** If `result_all_shops` is empty, then print a message instead of trying to find the `min`.

```
def solver(input_data, required_items):
    shops = build_shops(input_data)
    result_all_shops = []
    for shop_id,shop_info in shops.iteritems():
        this_shop = solve_one_shop(shop_info, required_items)
        if this_shop is not None:
            (price, solution) = this_shop
            result_all_shops.append([shop_id, price, solution])

    if result_all_shops:
        shop_id,total_price,solution = min(result_all_shops, key=(lambda x: x[1]))
        print('SHOP_ID=%s' % shop_id)
        sln_str = [','.join(items)+'(%0.2f)'%price for (price,items) in solution]
        sln_str = '+'.join(sln_str)
        print(sln_str + ' = %0.2f' % total_price)
    else:
        print "Item not available"
```

Comment: Thanks TOM. Its working, but there is one problem. If I call the code on  ---- shop_text = open('input-1.csv','rb')     
solver(shop_text,['burger', 'D']).  I get a TypeError,because items 'burger' & 'D' arent available together at any of the two shops. Instead of throwing TypeError, I want the program to just output - "Item not available"

Comment: @sunita that was confusing, you didn't say you had changed your input data! I've made a couple of changes above, which have hopefully fixed those problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can figure out the error if you do this:

In your `solve_one_shop` method, print the dictionary `shop` after the line `first_item = items[0]`. Doing that will print out:

`{'A': [[3.0, ['A']]], 'B': [[1.0, ['B']]], 'D': [[1.25, ['D']]], 'CCC': [[1.2, ['CCC']]]}`

So, `burger` is not one of its keys and hence it throws a `KeyError`

Add this line:
`2,1.25,burger`
to the end of your `input.csv` file and your code works fine.

Do the reading of values from the `shop` dictionary in a try except block to deal with the case where an item may not be present.

**Note:**
In your method `build_shops` the line:

```
shop_id,cost,items = item_info.replace('\n', '').split(',')
```

although strips off the newline, it does not strip off the carriage return. To fix that, do this:

```
shop_id,cost,items = item_info.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').split(',')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Warun, thanks but I think you got it wrong.Ive given output for two test files. See the first input-1.csv file does have an entry for burger, but still Im getting KeyError that burger not found. Whereas on input-2.csv the code runs perfectly fine. As you can see both the files have same structure(comma seperation) & format, but then why one of them is giving output whereas the other isnt ?

Comment: @sunita With input-2.csv the code runs fine because `CCC` is present for both the `shop_id` values 1 and 2 and hence will not hit the error at `for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:` Where as `input-1.csv` although has `burger` with `shop_id` value 1, it does not have `burger` for `shop_id` 2 and hence gives the error at `for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:`

Comment: Thanks warun, but how can I overcome this error ? If possible could you please fix my code. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for pointing out warun. Theres a small problem though. If I call the code on ---- shop_text = open('input-1.csv','rb') solver(shop_text,['burger', 'D']). I get a TypeError,because items 'burger' & 'D' arent available together at any of the two shops. Instead of throwing TypeError, I want the program to just output - "Item not available"